# Span Not Holding Continer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to put an icon on the far right side of my text inputs.  However, for the code that I currently have, the icons keep coming up above the div that holds the input box.  I can't figure out why it's busting out of the container.  JS Fiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/fjuovf1h/.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="container content">
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="sky-form" id="sky-form" method="post">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <header>Header</header>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
       <section class="col col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="inline">From</label>
         <span class="icon-append fa fa-plane"></span>
         <input class="form-control inline" id="flight_depart_city" name="flight[depart_city]" placeholder="City, State" type="text" />
        </div>
       </section>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS can be found on JSFiddle

Comment: please format your code correctly!

Comment: HTML fixed and formated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `span` has absolute positioning, so it will be placed relative to the closest parent that doesn't have static positioning. That happens to be the div with `class="col-md-12"`.

You can set positioning on the parent element for the fields, that will make the icon be placed relative to that:

```
.form-group { position: relative; }
```